# Source is not a java project : Can't create java class

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have been following the Spring guides. One particular [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/) has been causing some problems.

I'm using STS as my development environment. I pulled the initial version of the service registration and discovery using eureka guide, but when I try to create my java file `eureka-service/src/main/java/hello/EurekaServiceApplication.java` it gives me.

> Source Folder is not a java project.

Just to be sure I pulled the completed version of the guide. It's parent folder isn't a java project either but it has the `eureka-service/src/main/java/hello/EurekaServiceApplication.java` file in place.

Interestingly when I tried to create a new java file into the completed project I run into the same error.

So how do I create that java file also if my final aim is the completed guide whose parent directory is not a java project, should I make manual changes to the initial guide and make it a Java project?

Edit: The project also isn't recognized as a Spring-Boot app.

Answer (score 2):

In STS > Rightclick on project > properties > Project Facets > check java

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on Project --> Properties --> Project Facets --> Convert to Faceted Form --> Select Java --> Apply --> ok.

This should convert your project as a Java project.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried importing that particular guide using the "Import Getting Started Content" wizard and it does not get imported correctly.

The reason is that its a bit of an unusual layout compared to the other more typical guides. Rather than containing a single project it contains a parent pom and two sub-projects `eureka-client` and `eureka-server`. The "Import Getting Started Content" wizard isn't able to handle the more complex layout and just creates a generic project with all of the contents of the parent folder.

You can still import the projects manually and have them setup correctly using the normal way to import maven or gradle projects into Eclipse/STS.

For example to import the projects as maven projects do this:

- Go to "File >> Import >> Existing Maven Projects".
- Click "Next"
- Point the wizard at the `complete` directory of unzipped guide.
- Click finish

Comment: I did exactly as you have instructed when I import is initially, it was recognized as a maven project but it's a multi-project(`eureka-client`, `eureka-server`). My question is how to I run each sub-project separately.
Could you list out the steps to start `eureka-server` as a Spring Boot app.

Comment: That's really a different question... but... you can run it like any boot app in STS I think. There are number of ways. One way is simply to right-click the project and select "Run As >> Spring Boot App".

Comment: Another way is using the Spring boot dashboard. Select either one of the apps (or both of them at the same time) and click the "Start" button at the top of the dash to launch.

Comment: Please see my edit. So since it isn't recognized doesn't show up in the dashboard nor can I see the Run as option.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the complete repository, but import the projects individually.

I meant

- Go to "File >> Import >> Existing Maven Projects". Click "Next" Point
  the wizard at the Eureka Client directory of unzipped guide. Click finish

Repeat the same for importing Eureka Service.

You will get two different and separate projects to work on.

You should be able to get Run As --> Spring Boot Application option by now.

If not get into EurekaClientApplication.java class and Right Click and Run As --> Java Application to run the application.

Repeat the same for running Eureka Service application.

Comment: @Shanky Hope this has solved your problem. Could you please confirm the same by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven project case, right click on project -> Maven -> Update project can solve this problem.